Can I use Jellyfin and an external SSD with a RPI3b?
I've set up Jellyfin on my RaspberryPi 3b (V 1.2 if that matters?) and it works really well, I can watch my shows and haven't had loading issues.
My SD card is quite small unfortunately, so I want to get an SSD to store the rest of my media, however I'm seeing varying opinions on whether this will work with my model.
As far as I understand it the RPI3 only has USB2.0 which means the speed won't be great. What I don't know is if it's fast enough for Jellyfin. Will I be able to stream media (TV/Movies) from the SSD if it's connected via USB?
If not, what are my options? Can I get a network NAS and stream over my local network?

At best this question will be answered by opinions. You claim to have a storage problem (did you try a bigger SD Card?) with any details THEN wonder if SSD would be fast enough for your unspecified requirements.

This seems like a bit of a silly reply? SD cards aren’t for media storage, yeah I could spend £500 on a 1TB SD card, but obviously I won’t do that.
